# Loading php page using jquery/ajax to open specific links to display pages in a Div

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have mysql table with id/name/desc fields .I'm displaying it in div using php select query

```
<div class="show_name">
    while( $row = $data->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    { ?>
        <div><?php echo $row['id'];?></div>
        <div><?php echo $row['name'];?></div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

**jquery/ajax code**

```
$('.show_name').on('click',function(){
    $('#content').load('name.php');
});
```

i've name.php page where i want to display description of clicked name link

```
for example
id name
1   abc
2   xyz
```

if i click on abc name link i should be able to open name.php with abc desc

if i click on xyz name link i should be able to open same name.php with xyz desc

etc..

Please Any help is appricated Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put class and user defined data attribute for storing id

```
// add clickMe class
// and add data-id attribute
<div class="clickMe" data-id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['id'];?></div>
<div><?php echo $row['name'];?></div>
```

Then your js code should be like this :

```
// using on to delegate for dynamic element
$('.show_name').on('click','.clickMe', function(){
  // capture data id
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  // load name.php and pass post parameter(id)
  // we pass id paramater here
  // you can use success callback if want to populate anything
  $('#content').load('name.php', {id : id});
  // above code should display data from name.php
});
```

And inside your `name.php` should have queries and html page like :

```
// this id we pass from load request earlier 
$myId = $_POST['id'];
// do your logic here
// query from database for details description using where id = '$myId'
// display the content here
// suppose you have data store inside $myData variable
$myData = getData();
echo $myData['name'];
echo $myData['desc'];
```